# Error in Travis CI build, trying to complete SFDX Travis CI Trailhead module

Tags: salesforcedx, ci, cicd, developer-productivity

I've been struggling a lot trying to complete this [trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci). The first issue was while trying to log in with GitHub creds, which I solved using the GitHub-token flag.

Now, after I Kick-off Continuous Integration, it keeps failing over and over again.

The first exception was **iv undefined**, which is no longer happening, not sure how it got fixed.
And this last exception has become a real blocker. I can't figure out how to work around this.

Job Log:

[image]

Config File:

```
os: linux
dist: xenial
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.0.0
cache: false
env:
  - URL=https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_79bf14636734_key -iv $encrypted_79bf14636734_iv
    -in assets/certs/server.key.enc -out assets/certs/server.key -d
  - export SFDX_AUTOUPDATE_DISABLE=false
  - export SFDX_USE_GENERIC_UNIX_KEYCHAIN=true
  - export SFDX_DOMAIN_RETRY=300
  - export SFDX_DISABLE_APP_HUB=true
  - export SFDX_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - mkdir sfdx
  - wget -qO- $URL | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
  - "./sfdx/install"
  - export PATH=./sfdx/$(pwd):$PATH
  - sfdx --version
  - sfdx plugins --core
  - sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $CONSUMERKEY --jwtkeyfile assets/server.key
    --username $USERNAME --setdefaultdevhubusername -a HubOrg
script:
  - sfdx force:org:create -v HubOrg -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a ciorg --wait
    3
  - sfdx force:org:display -u ciorg
  - sfdx force:source:push -u ciorg
  - sfdx force:apex:test:run -u ciorg --wait 10
  - sfdx force:org:delete -u ciorg -p
```

I'm not sure what else to look at or do to make this work.

I'm trying to create a standard development pipeline, which is important to implement CI/CD.

Workstation settings:

- Ruby version: 2.7.2
- Travis version: 1.10.0
- SFDX-cli version: 7.85.1

Already tested in Windows (local station) and AWS Ubuntu server, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to solve it.

The reasons why this was failing:

1. Trailhead module information about login is out of date, travis login --org was not working- keep throwing "Not found" exception, so I solved it using travis login --org --github-token.
2. When using `travis encrypt-file path-to-secret-file/secret-file.txt path-to-secret-file/secret-file.txt.enc --add` I wasn't providing the endpoint, in this case since I was logged to the Org end-point I needed to specify the same in the command by adding `--org` at the end.
3. Since Travis-org is moving soon to Travis-com, and Travis-org only fetches public repositories, I needed to move this to Travis-com, so I logged out and logged in again but this time pointing to --com in both commands (login and encrypt-file).

Taking these 3 considerations I was able (finally) to make it work.

Is pretty bad not having this information accessible.

Only information that gave me an idea of what probably was happening was this banner.

[image]

Basically nothing.

For some reason login itself keeps failing, I was able to log in by creating a GitHub token for Travis following [this document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d63MP.png) and using `travis login --github-token`